# Documentum issue: Setup cannot copy the file ExJNIAPI.dll

Tags: documentum, webtop

I was using webtop for some time and it was working fine.

Now its started to give this error and if I cancel it, its asking to download some cab Files, which I allowed.

[image]

But again when installed it starts showing the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a required file for Documentum Webtop client side file transfer. Odds are, an update on the PC that you are viewing / editing files, has caused trouble.

Personally I would

1. back up any checked out files on local PC. By default (I think), would be in %USERPROFILE%\Documentum\CheckedOut
2. Reboot PC, to free up any processes holding locks on files and folders
3. Delete local UCF install, by default: %USERPROFILE%\Documentum
4. Login to Webtop and do fresh clean install

For futher troubles shooting take a look at
https://community.emc.com/people/aldago-zF7Lc/blog/2014/06/04/ucf-troubleshooting-v2
or in the new OpenText webtop forums
https://forums.opentext.com/forums/categories/documentum-webtop